# No Integer value of 0 in TableView using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

i have a Problem with the TableView in JavaFX. I have 3 Columns with Integer within. Right at the start, the default value of these cells should be null (JavaFX use "0" instead of nothing). My question: how can i show " " (nothing) instead of "0". I aldready use the setCellFactory to make my table editable. Here the Code:

```
_points1 = new TableColumn<Row, Integer>("Spieler 1");
    _points1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Row, Integer>("_valuePlayer1"));
    _points1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
    _points2 = new TableColumn<Row, Integer>("Spieler 2");
    _points2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Row, Integer>("_valuePlayer2"));
    _points2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
    _points3 = new TableColumn<Row, Integer>("Spieler 3");
    _points3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Row, Integer>("_valuePlayer3"));
    _points3.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
```

Comment: Integer in this case is misleading - it's a primitive integer not an object Integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with your `cellFactory`/`cellValueFactory`, but with your `Row` class. You're using `IntegerProperty`s. Those properties do not allow `null` values. If you attempt to set `null` as value using `IntegerProperty.setValue`, the value is automatically replaced with `0`. This results in the behavior you observed.

To allow `null` values you need to use `ObjectProperty<Integer>`s instead of `IntegerProperty`s.